# Understanding how ambiguous operators are selected in swift

Tags: swift, protocols, overloading

Here is a Swift Playground with two versions of the `+` operator:

```
protocol Value {
    func get() -> Float
}

func + (a:Value, b:Value) -> Float {
    print("Value.+")
    return a.get() + b.get()
}

func + (a:S, b:Value) -> Float {
    print("S.+")
    return a.get() + b.get()
}

struct S : Value {
    func get() -> Float {
        return 0
    }
}

struct T : Value {
    func get() -> Float {
        return 1
    }
}

let s1 = S()
let s2 = S()
let s3 = s1 + s2

let t1 = T()
let t2 = T()
let t3 = t1 + t2
```

When run I get the following output:

```
S.+
Value.+
```

Am I correct that the swift compiler is interpreting `S` as a more specific type than `Value` and that is why it is selecting `S.+` rather than `Value.+` for the first sum? Is this behavior established somewhere in the official swift docs?

Comment: The compiler will always select the more specific version of a function is several could be called, hence the behaviour you see.

Comment: Do you know where this behavior is documented by apple?

Comment: Sadly I cannot find this in the documentation now, but have a look at [this](https://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/09/24/which-function-does-swift-call-part-2-single-arguments/) blog post on the topic.